# How to expunge NSSplitView subview frames from the user defaults system?

Tags: swift, cocoa, frame, appkit, nssplitview

I want to reset the `NSSplitView` subview frames. You can already expunge the `NSWindow` frame using this:

```
NSWindow.removeFrame(usingName: "MyWindow")
```

I tried to expunge the `NSSplitView` subview frames by doing this:

```
NSWindow.removeFrame(usingName: "MySplitView")
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "NSSplitView Subview Frames MySplitView")
```

Is there a way?